# Executing gradle build tasks in custom tasks

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a custom task in gradle Called release and I want this task to execute the clean and build tasks:

```
task release
{
    //do something
    clean
    build
}
```

I know it is possible to call tasks from command line like

```
gradle build release
```

But I want to know  wether it is possible to execute build tasks within custom tasks?

Comment: see if this helps you out, https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use 'finalizedBy' feature either by configure it inside 'release' task:

```
task release
{
    finalizedBy clean, build

    // Do some stuff
}
```

or configure it after 'release' task:

```
release.finalizedBy clean, build
```

Note that [this feature](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html#org.gradle.api.Task:finalizedBy) is currently in incubation and may change in the future.

Comment: Thanks @yonisha It works but when `dependsOn clean, build` the build task executes first and then clean task executes so in that case the the build directory gets deleted. In my case I need release task to be executed first then clean and finally build task. Is there a way to execute the tasks in the order I have mentioned.?

Comment: Thanks @yonisha .. It works but when ` finalizedBy clean, build` is used build task executes first and then clean task is executed.

Comment: @SpencerBharath well, if that's deterministic then simply use 'finalizeBy build, clean' :) otherwise, open an issue on Gradle

Comment: By convention, Gradle executes task dependencies in alphabetical order.